# Having trouble with the list input in this code(How to make it work with custom list input?)

Tags: python

I have to take a list of integers as an input and then print out a histogram corresponding to each integer.

```
Ex: input = [4,9,7]
output: ****
        *********
        *******
```

This is the code that I wrote:

```
def histogram(list1):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        print (list1[i]* "*")

ls=input("Enter the numbers: ")
(histogram(ls))
```

But this is not working when I give the input 497(I also tried list(input)). But when I make the following change , it works:

```
def histogram(list1):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        print (list1[i]* "*")

input = [4,9,7]
histogram(input)
```

How do I write the code so that it works according to any input given by the user?

Comment: Your code works for me. How does the user provide input? If it's literally "`497`" you need to preprocess it first.

Comment: How is it working for you ? What input are you giving(and in what format?)? Because when I give any input, it gives me an error: can't multiply sequence by non-int type of str

Comment: Just copy pasting your code

Comment: Did you give an input and test it with that?
Which code are you talking about btw? The first or the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the user to enter a Python list, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to turn that into a real list:

```
import ast
ls = ast.literal_eval(input('Enter the numbers: '))
histogram(ls)
```

However, you could just ask them to enter the numbers separated by a space, and use `split`:

```
ls = [int(x) for x in input('Enter the numbers, separated by a space: ').split()]
histogram(ls)
```

Your `histogram` function can also be shortened to:

```
def histogram(list1):
    for i in list1:
        print (i * "*")
```

If you're using Python 2.x, you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Thanks , it's working with ast.literal_eval , but when I use the .split() function with my code(or the shortened version you suggested), I'm getting an error: "can't multiply sequence by non-int type of str"

Comment: My mistake! Edited that one to cast the input to ints first.

Comment: Could you explain a bit what you did here? Did you cast the list inputs to be int? (like ls=int(input))?

Comment: I used a list comprehension to take each element from the `split()` call, and cast it to ints: `[int(x) for x in input('...').split()]` - that returns a new list, with each element as integers instead of strings.

Comment: Thank you! Now everything is clear and it works perfectly! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `python3`

```
(histogram(eval(ls)))
```

or

```
import ast
(histogram(ast.literal_eval(ls)))
```

For `python2`

```
(histogram(ls))
```

**Demo**

```
Enter the numbers: [1,2]
*
**
```

Comment: `eval` is dangerous. As all you need them to enter is a list of integers, you could use `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 0):

A different solution:

```
def histogram(list1):
    for i in list1:
        print (i * "*")

ls=[]
while True:
    cur = input("Enter next number: ")
    if (cur == ""):
        break;
    ls.append(int(cur))

histogram(ls)
```